# acts_as_messagable doesn't work on rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using 'acts_as_messagable' gem for private messaging between users.

My model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_messageable :table_name => "messages"
..

end
```

I have error on start application:

```
`method_missing': protected method `default_scope' called for #<Class:0x007f84d7870da8> (NoMethodError)
```

current rails version 4.1, migrations are done.

What is the root of problem?

Comment: It's not compatible from the [docs](https://github.com/Stex/acts_as_messagable) Currently, the gem is compatible with Rails 2.3, an upgrade to Rails 3 is planned.  Or the older version which hasn't been touched since [2012](https://github.com/shannonwells/acts_as_messagable)

Comment: thank you for answer, it is sad but true, and I am switched back to mailboxer. can you do answer and I will mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not compatible from the docs:

> the gem is compatible with Rails 2.3, an upgrade to Rails 3 is planned